# How to setup login method to avoid duplicate code every test [selenium][java]

Tags: java, selenium, authentication

I want to use login method inted of repeat the same code every Test. I check similar topic here and couldn't find solution or just dont get it this.

Test is autogenerated by Selenium IDE so i have more question about some method there. I will mark things which confuse me. 
Its my test and method which i made:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Sortowanie{

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
String[] params;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  baseUrl = "https://en-testwebapi.poczta-polska.pl/";
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


@Test
  public void testSortowanie() throws Exception {
  driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
  login();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[2]")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[2]")).sendKeys("1");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]")).sendKeys("09");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]")).sendKeys("");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[4]")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[4]")).sendKeys("21");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[4]")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[4]")).sendKeys("");
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
  String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
  if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}
//I want to use params which will be defined in run configuration
public void login(){
    driver.findElement(By.id("p")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("p")).sendKeys(params[1]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("u")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("u")).sendKeys(params[0]);
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit_button")).click();
}
 //Where and when i need  to use this method ??
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
  try {
    driver.findElement(by);
    return true;
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
//Where and when i need  to use this method ??
private boolean isAlertPresent() {
  try {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    return true;
  } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
//Where and when i need  to use this method ??
private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
  try {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    if (acceptNextAlert) {
      alert.accept();
    } else {
      alert.dismiss();
    }
    return alertText;
  } finally {
    acceptNextAlert = true;
  }
}
}
```

So for the sake of peace i repeat my questions:
How can i make login method which get params value and where i need implement it?
How work method which i mark in comment on code above.

Any help will be usefull article, tutorials, similar code for analysis.

Thank you for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use page factory for this:

login class

```
package locators;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class login {

    @FindBy (id="p")
    public WebElement password;

    @FindBy (id="u")
    public WebElement user;

    public void Login(WebDriver driver, String login,String pass) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("p")));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(pass);
        user.clear();
        user.sendKeys(login);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit_button")).click();
        }}
```

your test

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import locators.login; // if your test class and login class in the same package there is no need to import it

public class Sortowanie{

private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  driver = new ChromeDriver(); // for some reason FF don't want to load this page for me
  baseUrl = "https://en-testwebapi.poczta-polska.pl/";
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


@Test
@Parameters({"login", "password"})
  public void testSortowanie(String login, String password) throws Exception {
  login L = PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class); //
  driver.get(baseUrl);
  L.Login(driver, login, password);

}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
  String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
  if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}
}
```

config xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Sortowanie Test Suite" verbose="2">

    <test name="Sortowanie Test 1" >
        <parameter name="login" value="login 1"/>   
        <parameter name="password" value="pass 1"/>
        <classes>
        <class name="orders.test_setup"/>
            <class name="Sortowanie"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Sortowanie Test 2" >
        <parameter name="login" value="login 2"/>   
        <parameter name="password" value="pass 2"/>
        <classes>
        <class name="orders.test_setup"/>
            <class name="Sortowanie"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: You say something about config file. It will be better idea but what i need to use for that.
Create setup.properties put login and pass value and how i can use that ?

Comment: Code doesn't work for me but you sugestion about config file was really helpfull.

Comment: I modified my code so that it runs on config file now. You have to run xml file as TestNG suite. Also my code wasn't working because I forgot about `import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;`.